# MySQL insert [Err] 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

It is too simple sql,but there is error.
The type of user_id is varchar,the type of times is also varchar.

```
insert into operationlog(user_id,times) VALUES('323423443' '2016-01-0415:');
```

Comment: you miss a `,` between the values: `VALUES('323423443',  '2016-01-0415:');`

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you are missing a comma in values brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You missed comma between two string values while inserting:

`insert into operationlog(user_id,times) VALUES('323423443','2016-01-0415:');`

Comment: Do not answer with code only. Explain what you have changed and why.